# Is there a way to take a 'snapshot' of a python debug session at a breakpoint?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to record the state (or take a 'snapshot') of all local/global variables (and call stack and other debug info) in a python debug session so that I can view it later?

I use VSCode with the Microsoft python extension to debug python. What I want to do is when I hit a breakpoint, like below, to have a way to save all the global/local variables so I can continue debugging and compare all the debug info between my saved 'snapshot' and the current state of the system.
[image]

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Doesn't have to be VSCode compatible, but that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `globals()` and `locals()` to obtain the current list of variables.

For example:

```py
a = 10

def f():
    i = 0
    j = 3
    print(locals())
    print(globals())

f()
```

Means:

```
{'i': 0, 'j': 3}
{'a': 10, 'f': ..., other pre-defined variables}
```

As for saving it, perhaps using tools like `pickle` or `dill` to create a binary representation of the dictionary and treat the generated file as a snapshot?

For example, when we save the variables to the file `snapshot.pkl`:

```py
import dill

a = 10

def f():
    i = 0
    j = 3
    with open('snapshot.pkl', 'wb') as fd:
        dill.dump({
            'locals': locals(),
            'globals': globals()
        }, fd)

f()
```

And then load it later in another file:

```py
import dill


with open('snapshot.pkl', 'rb') as fd:
    state = dill.load(fd)
    print(state['locals'])
```

Output:

```
{'i': 0, 'j': 3}
```

For the call stack, I'm not sure if you want a nicely formatted call stack or simply having the information, but you can simply obtain it via the `traceback` module with the function `traceback.format_stack` (or `traceback.print_stack`).